# CSS: микроотступ текста

Tags: padding, css

Есть вот такая вот штука:

[image: Imgur]

Как видно, текст слева чуть-чуть отъезжает от границы блока. Есть ли способ это дело отнормализовать без отрицательного margin-left?

Comment: Попробуй letter-spacing, заодно потереби padding-left.

Comment: @silksOfTheSoul, отступов там нет, letter-spacing тоже не помогает, начало текста не сдвигается вообще никак.

Comment: Это особенности шрифта, если умеете - отредактируйте шрифт, чтобы у него не было отступов слева, а если нет, то отрицательный left или margin-left.

Comment: @MasterAlex, это вообще дефолтный monospace ( ладно, хардкод так хардкод

Comment: @Etki, дефолтность шрифта не показатель того, что у него нет отступов слева для задуманного автором отображения текста, и отступ может быть разным в зависимости от шрифта :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это "проблема" моноширинных шрифтов. Там каждый глиф имеет одинаковую ширину, что достигается как раз за счет добавления подобных отступов. Используйте обычный шрифт.

Comment: Мда, я мог бы и догадаться, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, поможет или нет,
но, может, попробовать использовать свойства css `{display:inline-block;position:relative;left:10px}` для текста.

Comment: @Роман Соколов, нет, мне не хотелось бы хардкодить пиксели.